# Travelling to US on B1/B2 visa

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I had applied and got a B1/B2 visa for business travel last year. The trip got cancelled. However I am required to make a business trip again. The agenda is trainings and meetings.
On the invitation letter from client he has mentioned only trainings.
Now I am worried they would create issue for this as they might ask me whyI do not have a H3 since I am carrying a B1/B2 and invitation letter mentions only training

Answer (score 3):

Seems that both meetings and training are allowed under scope of B1/B2.

Relevant purposes of travel allowed on B1 visa:

> - **Conference, meeting, trade show, or  business event attendee** — Will receive no salary or income from a U.S based
>     company/entity. For  scientific, educational, professional or business
>     purposes.
> - **Training** — Participating in a training program that is not designed primarily to  provide employment. Will receive no payment or
>     income from a U.S.  based company/entity, other than an expense
>     allowance or expense  reimbursement related to traveler’s stay.

Source: [Dept. of State, Business Visa Purpose Listing](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf)